# Adding a command to the right click menu in Windows using Python

Tags: python, windows, menu, command, right-click

My question is, how to add a command to the right click menu using Python.
Note that this application is for Windows.

*I need to add the command here -*

[image: Image link]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is from Windows 11 and Microsoft has decided to make it difficult to add items on this system. You cannot do it with Python, [you need to write a shell extension](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/) in native code.

To add something in Windows 10 and older, add your command line to the default value [in](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151208-00/?p=92342) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\DesktopBackground\shell\my_thing\command`.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs) for more information about registering verbs.

Comment: Ok, so, how do I write a shell extension then?

Comment: Learn C++ and COM and then write it in C++. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623 but IExplorerCommand instead of IExecuteCommand .